# How can I access the latest state of value without setTimeout in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I need to call logEvent function inside useEffect hook only when the `searchTerms` string is changed. The problem is that `total_result` is equal to the previous state of value. So I need somehow get the actual latest value of `data?.hits.total.value`. That's why I am using setTimeout to get the latest value. Is it possible to do it without using setTimeout:

```
const hitsRef = useRef<undefined | number>();
  hitsRef.current = data?.hits.total.value;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      const log = setTimeout(() => {
        analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
          total_results: hitsRef.current,
          error_message: null,
        });
      }, 2000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(log);
      };
    }
  }, [searchTerms]);
```

Btw If I include `data?.hits.total.value` inside the useEffect array, it would log my function 2 times. Also because in some cases the total_results can be the same, so it will not call my logEvent function.

Here is how the code looks like

```
interface SearchResultsProps {
  refinement: string;
  searchTerms: string;
  currentPage: number;
}

const SearchResults: FunctionComponent<SearchResultsProps> = ({
  refinement,
  searchTerms,
  currentPage,
}) => {
  const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
  const { analyticsService } = useContainerProps();
  const shouldRender = searchTerms.length > 0;
  const { data, isFetching, isLoading } = usePagedQuery({
    refinement,
    terms: searchTerms,
    count: recordsPerPage,
    offset: (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
    queryEnabled: shouldRender,
  });

  const hitsRef = useRef<undefined | number>();
  hitsRef.current = data?.hits.total.value;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      const log = setTimeout(() => {
        analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
          total_results: hitsRef.current,
          error_message: null,
        });
      }, 2000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(log);
      };
    }
  }, [searchTerms]);
...
```

Comment: Can you add in your code how you update `total_result` state? Because you are saying the previous state is equal to the new state

Comment: @score30 Not actually state, I mean the value

Comment: Gotcha, where does `data` come from? If data comes from some where in your application that users interact with, you can use `useState` hook and store `data` in that whenever it gets updated. And then set `total_results` to the newly created state.

Comment: I think you can still update your question to include more codes for us to actually understand it like how you are updating your `data` and where.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `data?.hits.total.value` directly to `total_results`?

Comment: One question is, is the `usePagedQuery()` supposed to run every time the `searchTerms` change?

Comment: const usePagedQuery = ({
  queryEnabled = true,
  ...searchParameters
}: UsePagedQueryProps) =>
  useQuery({
    queryKey: ["search-results", searchParameters],
    queryFn: () => SearchService(axios).search(searchParameters),
    enabled: queryEnabled,
    keepPreviousData: true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
  });

I think no, here is how it looks like @DorjiTshering

Comment: @DorjiTshering yes I have tried assigning data?.hits.total.value directly to total_results. Then it returns the previous value of total result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250747/discussion-between-dorji-tshering-and-fatality99).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use setTimeout and useRef hook. Where data?.hits.total.value comes from? If data?.hits.total.value is a prop, You better save as a variable and pass directly inside useEffect like this:

```
const totalValue = data?.hits.total.value;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerms) {
      analyticsService?.logEvent(ANALYTICS_EVENTS.SEARCH_COMPLETED, {
          total_results: totalValue,
          error_message: null,
        });
      return () => {
        // clear request
      };
    }
  }, [searchTerms, totalValue]);
```

Now If Either searchTerms or totalValue is changed, useEffect re-render

Comment: I already wrote about the such case, read it again please. This solution would not work properly. First, it returns the log function twice. Second, it in some cases the total_results can be the same and searchTerms diffent, so it will not call my logEvent function.